# Elixir case-do construct and binding

Tags: elixir

I'm learning Elixir and am having trouble with a concept. Consider the following code:

```
iex(3)> case 1 do              
...(3)> x -> "x exists"        
...(3)> _ -> "something exists"
...(3)> end
"x exists"
iex(4)> x
** (CompileError) iex:4: undefined function x/0
```

The variable `x` isn't bound to anything yet, then how does the first `case` expression match? I thought it might be because Elixir is different from Erlang when it comes to assignment and so perhaps `x` gets bound in the process, but the command #4 shows that `x` isn't bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values bound in the patterns or body of a `case` expression are only available inside that branch.

```
case 1 do
  x -> IO.puts(x)
end
```

will print

```
1
```

If you want to extract a value from a `case`, you can store the return value of the `case` call:

```
x = case 2 do
  1 -> 2
  2 -> 3
  _ -> 0
end

x #=> 3
```

Comment: Sweet! I'll accept this as the answer as soon as SO allows me to. :-)